# Regulatory capital requirement for asset sales with recourse in the First Basel Accord

Tags: basel

In a BCBS working paper which listed the drawbacks of the first Basel Accord, [CAPITAL REQUIREMENTS AND BANK BEHAVIOUR:
THE IMPACT OF THE BASLE ACCORD by
Patricia Jackson et al.](https://www.bis.org/publ/bcbs_wp1.pdf), at p. 23,
is written:

> In cases when securitised assets have been previously “owned” by the
> bank, its credit enhancement is treated as “recourse,” which normally
> incurs an effective 100% (dollar-for-dollar) regulatory capital
> requirement. That is, the bank’s total regulatory capital requirement
> ratio is calculated as if the recourse position was immediately
> written off.

but I didn't manage to find this rule in the [First Basel Accord](https://www.bis.org/publ/bcbsc111.pdf).

In a footnote of the working paper is also specified:

> Typically, recourse incurs a total risk-based capital requirement
> equal to the lesser of (a) the amount of recourse provided (“low-level
> recourse”), and (b) 8 percent of the enhanced assets (i.e. equivalent
> to assigning a 100 percent risk-weight to the amount of enhanced
> assets).

In the Basel I document, the only place where I find "recourse" is in the table of the Credit Conversion Factors:

> Sale and repurchase agreements and asset sales with recourse, where
> the credit risk remains with the bank 100%

Where is the rule cited in the working paper?

Edit: making some further research I found a US Government document, [THE
FINANCIAL
CRISIS
INQUIRY REPORT](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GPO-FCIC/pdf/GPO-FCIC.pdf), where it's written:

> In October 2001, they introduced the “Recourse Rule” governing how
> much capital a bank needed to hold against securitized assets. If a
> bank retained an interest in a residual tranche of a mortgage
> security, as Keystone, Superior, and others had done, it would have to
> keep a dollar in capital for every dollar of residual interest. That
> seemed to make sense, since the bank, in this instance, would be the
> first to take losses on the loans in the pool. Under the old rules,
> banks held only 8% in capital to protect against losses on residual
> interests and any other exposures they retained in securitizations;
> Keystone and others had been allowed to seriously understate their
> risks and to not hold sufficient capital. Ironically, because the new
> rule made the capital charge on residual interests 100%, it increased
> banks’ incentive to sell the residual interests in securitizations—so
> that they were no longer the first to lose when the loans went bad.

So, is the dollar-for-dollar only a US rule? Does the standard Basel I framework implied only a regulatory capital for asset sales with recourse = 100% (CCF) $\cdot$ risk weight of the assets $\cdot$ 8%?

Comment: IANAL. Generally after a "sale with recourse" the seller even tough she no longer owns the asset, still has to pay some Claims that could occur against the asset. The buyer on the other hand does not have to pay those claims, so he can say that he owns the asset but is protected against some claims, a kind of "credit enhancement". But when the buyer and the seller are different entities in the same bank, it seems foolish (intuitively) to say that the risk(s) to the Bank have been meaningfully reduced, more like shifted around. The question for the Basel I regulators was how to penalize this.

Comment: @noob2 What you wrote is correct, of course, but I'm asking where the rule is in the First Accord document. I can't find where they indicate that, for recourse, there is a dollar-for-dollar requirement.